# addEventListener() devuelve null

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando ejecutar una función al cargar la página, si lo hago con *addEventListener* me devuelve **null**, sin embargo la misma función con *window.onload* funciona perfectamente.

Ejemplo con *window.onload*:

```
function saludar() {
    document.querySelector('#elem').innerHTML = 'Hola piti';
}

window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = saludar;
};
```

Código HTML:

```
<button id="btn">mostrar</button>
<div id="elem" ></div>
```

Si lo probáis funciona perfectamente, sin embargo ahora voy  hacer los mismo con el listener:

Ejemplo con addEventListener:

```
var target = document.querySelector('#btn');
    target.addEventListener('click', saludar, false);

function saludar() {
document.querySelector('#elem').innerHTML = 'Hola piti';
}
```

Veréis que en este último código devuelve null.

¿Cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo? a poder ser para ES6 y agradecería que fuese solo Javascript, nada de Frameworks ya que en jQuery u otros conozco como hacerlo.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Dónde colocas el código JavaScript? Si haces `document.querySelector` en un DOM aún no listo, te devuelva null.

Comment: Ese era el problema, sin embargo si hago document.getElementById() en un archivo externo me devolvía null igualmente,

Comment: El tag `<script>` por lo general siempre va aquí -> `<script src="..."></script></body>`. Justo antes del body, para evitar estos problemas y para menorar el tiempo de respuesta.

Comment: También puedes utilizar `DOMContentLoaded`. Revisa mi respuesta, la he actualizado.

Comment: Si la revise, funciona perfectamente.Mitsu soy nuevo preguntando! No se seleccionar respuesta correcta

Comment: Solo pasa el cursor al lado izquierdo de la respuesta y verás un mensaje: "Seleccionar respuesta..." con un check. Solo tienes que pulsarlo ;)

Comment: @UnderZero_- mira este link: es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  Básicamente al lado del 0 de cada respuesta te aparece un tick de color verde; selecciona la respuesta que te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es probable que tu código JS lo estés ejecutando cuando el DOM aún no está listo. Siempre es recomendable ponerlo antes del cierre del `<body>`, como embebido o como link (`<script src="...">`).

```html
<button id="btn">Mostrar</button>
<div id="elm"></div>

<script>
   const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
   btn.addEventListener('click', saludar);
  
   function saludar() {
      document.querySelector('#elm').innerText = 'Hola'; 
   }
</script>
```

O con ES6:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('#elm').innerText = 'Hola';
});
```

También puedes utilizar el evento `DOMContentLoaded` para ejecutar una acción en cuando se cargue el DOM.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // aquí todo tu código
});
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias! en cuanto el código esta en un archivo externo.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Lo que he comentado es falso; lo que realizas es *correcto* **pero** el problema debe de estar en que los elementos se cargan **DESPUÉS** de tu script; para comprobarlo sólo hace falta que abras la consola (F12) y verás un error de `undefined` o algo por el estilo. Para solucionarlo tienes varias maneras:

**1. Mover el código javascript** en la parte de abajo de tu página para que cargue después de la inicialización de los objetos **justo antes de cerrar el body tag** cómo indican **aquí**.

**2. Utilizar el window.onload** independientemente de dónde estén los scripts y colocar ahí tu declaración:

```
window.onload = function () {
    target.addEventListener('click', saludar, false);
}
```

---

---

Respuesta original:
Otra manera de utilizar `addEventListener` seria:

```
var target = document.querySelector('#btn');
target.addEventListener('click',  function() { document.querySelector('#elem').innerHTML = 'Hola piti'; }, false);
```

Fíjate que la función se define ahí mismo!

Por lo que puedes ver en [esta completísima respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/1468942) tienes muchas posibilidades.

Comment: En el caso del código del OP, es correcto, porque `saludar` es una función y se hace referencia a ella.

Comment: @MitsuGarcía Tienes razón; el problema será entonces por la carga de la página.

Comment: Así es, ese es el problema.

Comment: Si, doy por solucionado el tema, nos vemos por la comunidad.

Comment: @UnderZero_- no olvides seleccionar la respuesta correcta. Saludos.

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que con la primera opción ejecutas el código una vez se ha cargado la página (en el evento load del window), en cambio con la segunda opción el código (el addEventListener) se ejecuta de forma inmediata.

Si el código se encuentra antes de que esté definido el botón no te va a funcionar.

Dos opciones:

Incluye tu código al final de la página, una vez que esté creado el botón.

Ejecuta el código en el evento load del window, como en la primera opción:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var target = document.querySelector('#btn');
  target.addEventListener('click', saludar, false);
});

function saludar() {
  document.querySelector('#elem').innerHTML = 'Hola piti';
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">mostrar</button>
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Comment: Correcto, mi gracias ;)