# La operaciones en Javacript funcionan si los coloco en el archivo html pero no si lo enlazo en un archivo javacript

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos documentos uno llamado '`index.html`' y otro llamado '`Calculadora.js`' lo raro es que cuando enlazo `Calculadora.js` a traves de   `<script src="Calculadora.js"></script>` el codigo no me funciona pero cuando lo coloco abajo del codigo antes de cerrar el body, ahi si funciona perfecto. Que podria estar causando esto?, es decir, funcionaba bien cuando lo hacia a traves `prompt()` y `document.write()` pero al agregar `document.getElementById().innerHTML`, alli si no funciona, no me toma el `id` donde quiero que se imprima el resultado repito, estando en el documento anexo, no en el propio HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="Calculadora.js"></script> <!-- Asi no funciona -->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="practice">
            <p class="title">Calculadora de prueba para operaciones basicas a través de PROMPT</p>
            <p>El resultado es:</p>
            <div class="resultado-conatiner">
                <h2 id="operacion"></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let valorPrimero = 0, valorSegundo = 0, valor1 = 0, valor2 = 0, num1 = 0, num2 = 0, resultadoSuma = 0, resultadoFinal, continuidad = "", sumar = false, restar = false, seguirOperando = false;




valor1 = Number(prompt("Ingrese el primer valor"));
operacion = prompt("1(+) 2(-) 3(*) 4(/)")


do {

    
    sumar = ["1", "+"].includes(operacion);
    restar = ["2", "-"].includes(operacion);
    multiplicar = ["3", "*"].includes(operacion);
    dividir = ["/", "4"].includes(operacion);

    valor2 = Number(prompt("Ingrese el segundo valor"));

    if (sumar) {
        suma(valor1,valor2)
    } 
        else if (restar) {
        resta(valor1, valor2)
        } 
            else if (multiplicar) {
            multiplica(valo1,valo2)
            }
                else if (dividir) {
                    divide(valor1,valor2)
                }

    valor1 = resultado;
    operacion = prompt("1(+) 2(-) 3(*) 4(/) o terminar el programa(5)")
    seguirOperando = ["1","2","3","4","+","-","*","/"].includes(operacion);

} while (seguirOperando)

resultadoFinal = document.getElementById('operacion');

let htmlContent = resultado;

resultadoFinal.innerHTML = htmlContent;




function suma(num1, num2){
    resultado = num1 + num2;
    return resultado;
}

function resta(num1, num2) {
    resultado = num1 - num2;
    return resultado;
}

function multiplica(num1, num2) {
    resultado = num1 * num2;
    return resultado;
}

function divide(num1,num2) {
    resultado = num1 / num2;
    return resultado;
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Index y calculadora estan en la misma carpeta?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [addEventListener() devuelve null](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14177/addeventlistener-devuelve-null)

Comment: Exactamente, ahora funciona perfecto te lo agradezco mucho padaleiana ♥

Comment: No te funciona porque colocas el script al comienzo de tu archivo HTML, entonces cuando trata de buscar los elementos que tienes en el JavaScript, no los encuentra. Te recomiendo colocarlos antes del cierre de la etiqueta body